# Prove a Norm-Based Identity Involving Convex Combination

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $\textbf{x},\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta \in [0,1]$.
> I would like to show that
> $$
> \theta \|\textbf{x}\|^2 + (1-\theta) \|\textbf{y}\|^2 - \| \theta \textbf{x} + (1-\theta) \textbf{y} \|^2 = \theta (1-\theta) \|\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}\|^2 .
> $$

My try:
Note that, by triangle inequality, we have
$
 \| \theta \textbf{x} + (1-\theta) \textbf{y} \|^2 
 \leq (\| \theta \textbf{x}  \|  + \|  (1-\theta) \textbf{y} \|)^2 = \theta^2 \|  \textbf{x}  \|^2 + 2\theta (1-\theta) \| \textbf{x}\| \| \textbf{y}\|  +   (1-\theta)^2 \| \textbf{y} \|^2.
$
This implies that
\begin{align*}
  \theta \|\textbf{x}\|^2 + (1-\theta) \|\textbf{y}\|^2 - \| \theta \textbf{x} + (1-\theta) \textbf{y} \|^2
  & \geq \theta \|\textbf{x}\|^2 + (1-\theta) \|\textbf{y}\|^2 - [\theta^2 \|  \textbf{x}  \|^2 + 2\theta (1-\theta) \| \textbf{x}\| \| \textbf{y}\|  +   (1-\theta)^2 \| \textbf{y} \|^2] \\
  & = \theta \|\textbf{x}\|^2 (1-\theta) + (1-\theta) \|\textbf{y}\|^2 \theta -  2\theta (1-\theta) \| \textbf{x}\| \| \textbf{y}\|   \\
 & =  \theta (1-\theta) [ \|\textbf{x}\|^2  +  \|\textbf{y}\|^2  -  2 \| \textbf{x}\| \| \textbf{y}\| ]   \\
  & =  \theta (1-\theta) [ \|\textbf{x}\|-  \|\textbf{y}\|]^2   \\
 \end{align*}
Then I get stuck since the reversed triangle inequality works the other way around. Any comment/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I presume you mean the Euclidean norm. Expand out $\| (1-\theta) \textbf{y} \|^2$ and $ \theta (1-\theta) \|\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}\|^2$ using the dot product and the dot product terms will cancel.

Comment: Thanks, @Zoe Allen. But I was thinking that identity can hold for any $\ell_p$-norm, not just Euclidean 2-norm.

Comment: You should state which norms you are considering in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use triangle inequalities here. Just recall that $\lVert x\rVert^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$, and use the bilinearity of the scalar product:
\begin{align*}
\theta \lVert x\rVert^2+(1-\theta)\lVert y\rVert^2-\langle\theta x+(1-\theta)y,\theta x+(1-\theta)y\rangle & = \theta \langle x,x\rangle+(1-\theta)\langle y,y\rangle \\
& \qquad - \theta^2\langle x,x\rangle-(1-\theta)^2\langle y,y\rangle \\
& \qquad -2\theta(1-\theta)\langle x,y\rangle \\
& = \theta(1-\theta)(\lVert x\rVert^2+\lVert y\rVert^2-2\langle x,y\rangle)\\
& = \theta(1-\theta)\lVert x-y\rVert^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. @Gibbs. If the norm is not 2-norm but any $\ell_p$-norm, I am wondering if the identity still holds.

Comment: No, it does not in general. It is easy to write down a counterexample. Take e.g. $n=3$, $x=(1,2,0)$, $y=(1,1,1)$, the $\ell_3$-norm, and $\theta = 0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is false for other $\ell_p$ norms. Try substituting in $x = e_1$ and $y = e_2$ and $\theta = \frac{1}{2}$, for example. You get a formula which you eventually simplifies to $p=2$.

Comment: I see. Many Thanks!!